# Select immediate following image of only 1 class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select only the follwing img of a class using jQuery.

Shouldn't this work:

```
$('.upload_preview').next('img').attr('src',imgurl);
```

This works perfectly fine and will populate all img tags, but I just need the immediate follwing one

```
 $('.upload_preview img').attr('src',imgurl);
```

The problem I am having is there are multiple upload fields. Once I upload an image I need to grab that immediate img tag and populate it. This is going inside a click function using the Wordpress Media Uploader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.upload_preview img').first().attr('src',imgurl);
```

You stated that using `$('.upload_preview img')` got all of your images, so from that set simply take the `.first()` one...

Note that "immediate following image" is a misleading way to describe the image element if the image is *inside* the `'.upload_preview'` element (which it must be for your second line of code to do what you say it does). "First child image" might be a better way to put it.

Comment: Thank you! This is doing exactly what I need. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get it correctly, but if you have images inside .upload_preview then

```
$('.upload_preview img').next('img:first').attr('src', imgurl);​​
```

should do the trick

Comment: Won't that still select multiple images? First you select all the images inside `.upload_preview`, and then you select all of the images that are immediately following any of the ones you already selected...